# Trying to transfer photos from iPhone 5S to Windows 8.1 machine; only about 25 of the 1000+ photos show up in file explorer

Tags: iphone, photos, windows, file-transfer

My wife and I are heading to Europe tomorrow and want to free up space for pictures on her phone. I use iPhoto on my mac, but we want to transfer her pictures from her iPhone 5S to our Windows 8.1 pc I built.

The phone shows up in explorer, but when you click through to the DCIM folder, two subfolders show up, each with only 10-15 pictures. There are probably over 1000 on the phone, so how do I get to them? I've tried using Device Manager to delete the Apple driver, then letting Windows reinstall it. No change.

There was a strange photo or icon that showed in one of the folders. Sometimes it looked like a picture that failed to load (maybe something is corrupted)? Other times it looked like an odd windows icon.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [Photo Gallery](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-live/photo-gallery) [part of Windows Essentials] which can download photos very similarly to how iPhoto does it - rather than trying to hack around the raw file structure, which was never meant to be played in.

Comment: Okay thanks - I'll give it a try when the wife gets back tonight. This is something different from the Photos app in Windows 8.1, correct?

Comment: tbh, I've never used 8 or 8.1 - I've 7 & 10 preview here - so I'm not certain.